# Android Facebook Login button XML error

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I want to create a test project works 'facebook login'.
I made with reference to the developers site and blog equal, But I met with an error message on xml.

[error massage]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.facebooktest.zoit.facebooktest/com.facebooktest.zoit.facebooktest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

[xml]

```
   <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

[Manifest]

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.facebooktest.zoit.facebooktest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

      <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

</manifest>
```

[MainActivity]

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);



 facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, 
    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {...

      ...
 public void onActivityResult(...
 void geHashKey(){...
 void geHashKey(){ ...
 public void onResume(){ ...
 public void onPause(){...
```

Do you know what's wrong? please help.

Answer (score 0):

I know!

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

"setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);"
I succeeded to move the this code below to Facebook code.